# feature selection using kernel PCA (KPCA)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have tried Principal component analysis  (PCA) for feature selection which gave me 4 optimal features from set of nine features (Mean of Green, Variance of Green, Std. div. of Green , Mean of Red, Variance of Red, Std. div. of Red, Mean of Hue, Variance of Hue, Std. div. of Hue, i.e. [  MGcorr,VarGcorr, stdGcorr,MRcorr,VarRcorr,stdRcorr,MHcorr,VarHcorr,stdHcorr  ])  for classification of data into two clusters. From Literature, it seems that PCA is not very good method but rather is better to apply kernel PCA  (KPCA) for the feature selection. I want to apply KPCA for  feature selection and I have tried following:

```
d=4; % number of features to be selected, or d: reduced dimension
[Y2 eigVector para ]=kPCA(feature,d); % feature is 300X9 matrix with 300 as number of  
                                      % observation and 9 features
                                      % Y: dimensionanlity-reduced data
```

Above kPCA.m function can be downloaded from :
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39715-kernel-pca-and-pre-image-reconstruction/content/kPCA_v1.0/code/kPCA.m

In above implementation I want to know how to find  which 4 features from 9 features to select (i.e. which top features are optimal) for clustering.

Alternatively, I also tried following function for KPCA implementation:

```
options.KernelType = 'Gaussian';
options.t = 1;
options.ReducedDim = 4;
[eigvector, eigvalue] = KPCA(feature', options);
```

In above implementation also I have same problem in determining the  4 top /optimal features from set of 9 features.

Above KPCA.m function can be downloaded from : 
http://www.cad.zju.edu.cn/home/dengcai/Data/code/KPCA.m

That will be great if someone will help me in implementing kernel PCA for my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PCA doesn't provide optimal features per se.  What it provides is a new set of features that are uncorrelated.  When you select the "best" 4 features, you are picking the ones that have the greatest variance (largest eigenvalues).  So for "normal" PCA, you simply select the 4 eigenvectors corresponding to the 4 largest eigenvalues, then you project the original 9 features onto those eigenvectors via matrix multiplication.

From the link you provided for the kernel PCA function, the return value `Y2` appears to be the original data transformed to the top `d` features of the kernel-PCA space, so the transformation is already done for you.